# Error NodeJS e quando utilizar "=>"

Tags: javascript, node.js

Boa tarde,

Gente eu estou iniciando meus estudos com a tecnologia Node.js, porém quando tentei escrever o código de um web server exemplo:

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
   res.statusCode = 200;
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
   res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
   console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

O meu retorno gera o seguinte erro:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
                                             ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

O meu Node.js foi baixado a partir do código fonte do GitHub(v0.10.29).

OBSERVAÇÃO: Já procurei na internet e não consegui nada explicando, quando utilizar `=>`. Eu não entendo e se alguém pode me ajudar com alguma referência ou explicação ficarei grato em saber como funciona o `=>`.

Comment: Editaste a pergunta mudando o erro (!)... não era esse o erro que tinhas? Mudar o erro é esconder o problema...

Comment: O erro permanece do jeito que está ai, o problema é que eu testei com function + arrow e só o arrow entendeste? Do mesmo jeito que está escrito o código acima está o erro.

Comment: É que eu tinha colado o erro com "function".

Comment: @drigols Leia [O Stack Overflow em Português é um fórum?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/5878). Você não precisa alterar o título da pergunta para indicar que o problema foi resolvido. Ao aceitar uma resposta você já faz essa indicação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se usas *arrow functions* não podes usar a palavra reservada `function`, [como tinhas inicialmente na pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/207245/1).

Mais ainda, a versão `0.10.xx` do Node não suporta *arrow functions*, o suporte completo é só a partir da verão `6.4.0`. Podes ver a tabela de compatibilidade aqui: http://node.green/#ES2015-functions-arrow-functions

Ou seja:

Errado:

```
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) => {
```

Correto, usando *arrow functions*, usando versões recentes do Node.js:

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
```

Correto, usando `function`:

```
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res){
```

Comment: Boa tarde, Obrigado pelo a parte "Arrow functions" eu não saberia sobre... Mas o que ocorre é que mesmo utilizando sem "function" do jeito que você falou o erro permanece... Se você olhar bem não tem function a minha arrow.

Comment: @drigols no erro tem, é esse o código que o Node está a usar.

Comment: @drigols verifica o teu código e certifica-te que esse erro não existe noutras partes do código, e confirma com a linha que o erro indica.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está usando uma versão muito antiga do NodeJS

Como você mesmo disse está usando a versão v0.10.29, ela é de 2014 e me parece que somente após a versão 4.4.5 de 2016 é que foi adicionado suporte a ES6, que inclui o arrow function